# Serializing List to JSON Array

Tags: java, json, spring, jpa, jackson

I have a JPA entity with a List of custom objects as one of its fields. Using a Jackson converter, I've managed to persist this list as a JSON array into a MySQL database, but Iam unable to insert into this list after its initial creation.

I can successfully retrieve the existing list, add a new object in memory(and test that it has been inserted), then save it via a Spring REST repository. However, it never seems to persist. Any ideas? Here is my code (this is a Spring Boot project FYI):

**Candidate entity with a List inside**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Candidates", schema = "Candidate")
public class Candidate extends ResourceSupport {

@Id
@Column(name = "CandidateID")
private Long candidateID;

// More fields

@Column(name = "Fields")
@Convert(converter = CollectionConverter.class)
private List<CandidateField> fields;

//Getters & setters
}
```

**CandidateField class which makes up the List above. The CandidateField is simply a POJO that models the JSON stored in a single field in the Candidate table, it is not an independent entity.**

```
public class CandidateField {

private Long fieldID;
private String name;
private boolean current;

public CandidateField () {

}

public CandidateField (Long fieldID, String name, boolean current) {
    this.fieldID = fieldID;
    this.name = name;
    this.current = current;
}

//Getters & Setters
}
```

**Converter**

```
public class CollectionConverter implements AttributeConverter<List<CandidateField>, String> {

private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

@Override
public String convertToDatabaseColumn(List<CandidateField> object) {
    try {
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
}

@Override
public List<CandidateField> convertToEntityAttribute(String data) {
    try {
        return objectMapper.readValue(data, new TypeReference<List<CandidateField>>() {});
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Code that persists to database**

```
public void addField(Long fieldID, Long candidateID) {
    Candidate candidate = repository.findOne(candidateID);
    candidate.getFields().add(new CandidateField(fieldID, "", true));
    repository.saveAndFlush(candidate);
}
```

**Repository**

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface CandidateRepository extends JpaRepository<Candidate,Long>{}
```

I can't seem to figure out why this won't persist. Any help will be very much appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Consider defining the [cascade type](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html#cascade--) for your collection.

When you persist your `Candidate` objects the operation is not cascaded by default and thus you need to define it yourself unless you persist your `CandidateField` objects directly.

Comment: Hey Brian, 
Cascade types are only applicable to entities are they not? The CandidateField is simply a POJO that models the JSON stored in a single field in the Candidate table, it is not an independent entity. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing out that CandidateField is just a POJO. I somehow overlooked it. But if you are willing to provide a stripped down test case (maybe in conjunction with JUnit) with an in memory database, I'd be happy to take another look at it.